# google not indexing my page

Tags: search, google-index

I search for a complete phrase in google **"visitors had the opportunity to swing them to-and-fro. Never had i experienced so "** ", the comment from the post "http://radhanathswamiweekly.com/radhanath-swami-describes-jhulan-yatra-festival/"

the comment is posted by "kiran shetty" **a month ago.** in that post.

the Google search results are:

> No results found for "visitors had the opportunity to swing them
>   to-and-fro. Never had i experienced so ".

Google cache says:

> This is Google's cache of
>   http://radhanathswamiweekly.com/radhanath-swami-describes-jhulan-yatra-festival/.
>   It is a snapshot of the page as it appeared on 18 Sep 2014 08:00:49
>   GMT. The current page could have changed in the meantime. Learn more

Using "**Fetch as Google**" from the webmaster for the post:http://radhanathswamiweekly.com/radhanath-swami-describes-jhulan-yatra-festival/

> the fetch status shows as **completed**.

Google fetch's **Downloaded HTTP response** can be found at: "http://pastebin.com/v4L1nuG3"

The **Downloaded HTTP response** contains the complete phrase "visitors had the opportunity to swing them to-and-fro. Never had i experienced so ".

> **That means google is able to see the text.**

Since the cache shows that its cached on 18-sep. the comment is one month old (23-aug) from today (23-sep). Then why it is not getting indexed, as we see its not showing in the search results, even though the text exists in the http response which google sees the page as.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is known and indexed by Google, you can verify this by running the following command in the Google search box:

```
site:radhanathswamiweekly.com/radhanath-swami-describes-jhulan-yatra-festival/
```

The query you are using is very very specific and it is a bit long for Google to prepare search results for it. Not many people will type that query.

You can go through a checklist I maintain if you are looking for [more reasons why your page is not ranking](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/page-is-not-ranking-checklist.html).

Comment: Thank you to show me a way to check whether the page is getting indexed or not. If the page is getting indexed then why is it not searching the text.

Comment: Google does not always index all the text. It is their decision. Usually, when they don't do it, it is because they think it is not interesting enough (of course, you will disagree with this... lol)

Comment: Then there is no answer to this question. thank you.